# Python Jupyter Notebook won't run my code, keeps reconnecting

Tags: python, url, multiprocessing, jupyter-notebook, urllib

How come this piece of code does not run properly on Jupyter Notebook.
It keeps reconnecting without any result. I try to make a database and scrape data as fast as possible from a webserver. I use threads to speed up the process and iterate over multiple url's (every different url represent a different day).

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import urllib
import requests
from pprint import pprint
import time
from io import StringIO
from multiprocessing import Process, Pool

symbols = ['AAP']

start = time.time()
dflist = []


def load(date):
    if date is None:
        return
    url = "http://regsho.finra.org/FNYXshvol{}.txt".format(date)
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(url,delimiter='|')
        if any(df['Symbol'].isin(symbols)):
            stocks = df[df['Symbol'].isin(symbols)]
            print(stocks.to_string(index=False, header=False))
            # Save stocks to mysql
        else:
            print(f'No stock found for {date}' )
    except urllib.error.HTTPError:
        pass


pool = []
numdays = 365
start_date = datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 15 )  #year - month - day
datelist = [
        (start_date - datetime.timedelta(days=x)).strftime('%Y%m%d') for x in range(0, numdays)
        ]

pool = Pool(processes=16)
pool.map(load, datelist)

pool.close()
pool.join()

print(time.time() - start)
```

Would like to know how I can solve this and make it work

Comment: One thing I see that could be causing a problem is your blanket `except: pass` statement. If you're getting any http errors, you're suppressing them when they might tell you exactly what the problem is

Comment: I tried `except: pass` to `except: print(f'No URL for this date: {url}')`, but that did not fix it... @G.Anderson

Comment: Even leaving the `except urllib.error.HTTPError` in might be suppressing errors that aren't that specific `urllib` error. Rather than doing a `try: except:` block at all, what happens if you just try to run it and see what error it throws? My intuition is that your "scrape data as fast as possible from a webserver" , especially for a regulatory body like FINRA, is raising all sorts of red flags and at the very least your IP is being rate-limited and/or triggering any number of anti-scraping and anti DOS measures

Comment: I initially tried without threading and I would scrape data every second and that was fine. Even if I set processes to 1, numdays = 1, which means I scrape 1 day with 1 process it doesn't work, and it's impossible that this little amount of scraping is triggering anything. It must be something else. @G.Anderson